# Can str() fail in Python?

Tags: python

Are there any cases where `str()` throws an exception in Python?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I looked here first: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str The answer: nothing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it can fail for custom classes:

```
>>> class C(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return 'oops: ' + oops
...
>>> c = C()
>>> str(c)
NameError: global name 'oops' is not defined
```

It can even fail for some of the built-in classes, such as `unicode`:

```
>>> u = u'\xff'
>>> s = str(u)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xff' in position 0:
ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: `str(u"\xff")` fails in Python 2 only.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, of course:

```
class A(object):
    def __str__(self):
        raise Exception
a = A()
str(a)
```

Comment: +1: Rather than a contrived example, this is -- effectively -- what happens.  We're allowed to fill in any exception-raising code.  Nice.

Comment: In what way is this different from what you meant?  The invocation of `str` raises an exception, which sounds exactly like what you're asking about.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the object you're calling `str()` on. Each object can define it's own implementation in a `__str__()` function and this could easily throw an exception.

Example:

```
class A:
  def __str__(self):
    raise Exception

str(A())
```